# Update client using API call in fineract

Tags: apache-fineract

Does anyone know how to update **'fullname'** in fineract using api call?
When I did I am getting

> "Server Error","exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException","message":"No message available"

I followed https://fineract.apache.org/docs/legacy/index.html#clients

But for updating client fullname was not useful

Comment: Please add enough code to create a [mre] - [ask]